# issue with sorting with multiple key value and making new associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have get associative array structure in api responce like below

```
{
    "error": false,
    "msg": "Success",
    "result_user_wish_list": {
        "my_whishlist": [
            {
                "id": 6,
                "product_name": "abc",
                "price": 300,
                "user_id": 6,
                "shop_name": 12,
                "is_buy": 0,
                "purchase_by": null,
                "created_at": "2020-07-01T21:34:43.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-07-01T21:34:43.000000Z",
                "shop_name": "Relience",
                "shop_zipcode": "390016",
                "user_name": "ABC"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "product_name": "Rice",
                "price": 1200,
                "user_id": 1,
                "shop_id": 10,
                "is_buy": 0,
                "purchase_by": null,
                "created_at": "2020-06-16T12:02:04.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-07-03T16:06:42.000000Z",
                "shop_name": "Dmart",
                "shop_zipcode": "390017",
                "user_name": "XYZ"
            }
        ],
        "my_friends_list": [
            [
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "product_name": "Rice",
                    "price": 1200,
                    "user_id": 1,
                    "shop_id": 12,
                    "is_buy": 0,
                    "purchase_by": null,
                    "created_at": "2020-06-16T12:02:04.000000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2020-07-03T16:06:42.000000Z",
                    "shop_name": "Relience",
                    "shop_zipcode": "390016",
                    "user_name": "MNJ"
                }
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

and I want to make another array from this array like if we have same `shop_name` and same `shop_zipcode` then make another array from this array like

```
        Array
        (
            [Relience] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [product_name] => Jelitte Leggings Black Color Ankle Length
                    [price] => 300
                    [user_id] => 6
                    [shop_id] => 12
                    [is_buy] => 0
                    [purchase_by] => 
                    [created_at] => 2020-07-01T21:34:43.000000Z
                    [updated_at] => 2020-07-01T21:34:43.000000Z
                    [shop_name] => Relience
                    [shop_zipcode] => 390017
                    [user_name] => Fazal
                )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [product_name] => Rice
                        [price] => 1200
                        [user_id] => 1
                        [shop_id] => 12
                        [is_buy] => 0
                        [purchase_by] => 
                        [created_at] => 2020-06-16T12:02:04.000000Z
                        [updated_at] => 2020-07-03T16:06:42.000000Z
                        [shop_name] => Relience
                        [shop_zipcode] => 390017
                        [user_name] => Fazal
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [product_name] => Rice
                        [price] => 1200
                        [user_id] => 1
                        [shop_id] => 12
                        [is_buy] => 0
                        [purchase_by] => 
                        [created_at] => 2020-06-16T12:02:04.000000Z
                        [updated_at] => 2020-07-03T16:06:42.000000Z
                        [shop_name] => Relience
                        [shop_zipcode] => 390017
                        [user_name] => Mohini
                    )

            )

            [Dmart] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [product_name] => Colgate
                            [price] => 1200
                            [user_id] => 4
                            [shop_id] => 6
                            [is_buy] => 0
                            [purchase_by] => 
                            [created_at] => 2020-06-16T12:02:40.000000Z
                            [updated_at] => 2020-06-16T12:02:40.000000Z
                            [shop_name] => Dmart
                            [shop_zipcode] => 
                            [user_name] => Mohini
                        )
                )
        )
```

I have use below function to sort this arrays

```
function group_by($key, $data) {
    $result = array();

    foreach($data as $val) {
        if(array_key_exists($key, $val)){
            $result[$val[$key]][] = $val;
        }else{
            $result[""][] = $val;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
$byGroup =  $this->group_by("shop_name", array_merge($my_wish_list,$my_friends_wishlist[0]));
    print_r($byGroup); die();
```

but with this I can only sort arrays by shop_name and I want I can sort array by shop_name and shop_zipcode both

can anybody help me this this

Comment: First of all, this is not sorting. Sorting is changing the _order_, not the _structure_. Secondly, please post example data where input and output actually match. Your input data does not even contain `Jelitte Leggings Black Color Ankle Length` anywhere, yet it magically appears in the result somehow.

Comment: Can there be more than one postcode per shop name? If so, what result do you actually want then? Because the current structure you have shown, does not really appear to contain any grouping by postcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a json response first you will need to decode it by `json_decode` and then treat it as an array.

```
$decode = json_decode($data,true); //$data is your json response

$result = [];
for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($decode['result_user_wish_list']['my_whishlist']) ; $i++) { 
 for ($j=0; $j < sizeof($decode['result_user_wish_list']['my_friends_list'][0]) ; $j++) { 
  if ($decode['result_user_wish_list']['my_whishlist'][$i]['shop_name'] == $decode['result_user_wish_list']['my_friends_list'][0][$j]['shop_name'] && 
   $decode['result_user_wish_list']['my_whishlist'][$i]['shop_zipcode'] == $decode['result_user_wish_list']['my_friends_list'][0][$j]['shop_zipcode']) {
   $result[$decode['result_user_wish_list']['my_whishlist'][$i]['shop_name']][] = $decode['result_user_wish_list']['my_whishlist'][$i];
   $result[$decode['result_user_wish_list']['my_whishlist'][$i]['shop_name']][] = $decode['result_user_wish_list']['my_friends_list'][0][$j];
  }
  else{
   $result[$decode['result_user_wish_list']['my_whishlist'][$i]['shop_name']][] = $decode['result_user_wish_list']['my_whishlist'][$i];
  }
 } 
}
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [Relience] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [product_name] => abc
                    [price] => 300
                    [user_id] => 6
                    [shop_name] => Relience
                    [is_buy] => 0
                    [purchase_by] => 
                    [created_at] => 2020-07-01T21:34:43.000000Z
                    [updated_at] => 2020-07-01T21:34:43.000000Z
                    [shop_zipcode] => 390016
                    [user_name] => ABC
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [product_name] => Rice
                    [price] => 1200
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [shop_id] => 12
                    [is_buy] => 0
                    [purchase_by] => 
                    [created_at] => 2020-06-16T12:02:04.000000Z
                    [updated_at] => 2020-07-03T16:06:42.000000Z
                    [shop_name] => Relience
                    [shop_zipcode] => 390016
                    [user_name] => MNJ
                )

        )

    [Dmart] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [product_name] => Rice
                    [price] => 1200
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [shop_id] => 10
                    [is_buy] => 0
                    [purchase_by] => 
                    [created_at] => 2020-06-16T12:02:04.000000Z
                    [updated_at] => 2020-07-03T16:06:42.000000Z
                    [shop_name] => Dmart
                    [shop_zipcode] => 390017
                    [user_name] => XYZ
                )

        )

)
```